# How to convert pre-DSpace 7.x legacy items into entities during migration

Tags: dspace

I am migrating instances of Dspace 5 & 6 to DSpace 7 and need some pointers on converting legacy items, authors, etc. into entities supported by DSpace.

I have nanaged to move the items as is and enebled enties in the test instance of DSpace 7. However, I am stuck on how existing legacy items from pre-DSpace 7 can be flagged as correspoing enabled entities.
items -> publications
authors -> persons

Thank you